# Shower as humidifier -- yea or nay?

Tags: shower, fans, humidity, humidifier, exhaust

During the winter I often do not run the bathroom fan during/after a shower, figuring the house can use the additional humidity. Of course that means waiting for the water vapor to diffuse out of this small room.

It just occurred to me that I don't *have* to wait; I could use a fan (portable or built in) to encourage this.  With the disadvantage of also increasing airflow over the litterbox, admittedly, unless I also vent air directly into the shower area.

Completely stupid concept, or worth further thought?

Comment: Think the problem would be the humidly levels would up and down, probably more down than up.  For comfort you would want more constant level.  It should help to increase humidly to the rooms close to the shower, but less in rooms further away.  If you have a forced air heating system can place a humidifier on it.

Comment: In the past I would sometimes leave a pan of water  on a radiator as a slow humidifier. Now that I'm hearing mostly with the minisplit heat pump, that trick doesn't work... and with no central blower, I can't do a real central humidifier, though the minisplits do have fans and I'm playing with a homebrew "return" blower to offset ground-floor heat rising through stairwell, so circulation might be decent.

Comment: And yeah, erratic, granted. And frequent cycling might not be great for wooden furniture. Hm.

Comment: Do you have specific info that your humidity is lower in winter than summer? I suppose it depends where you live but here is completely the opposite. It's 89% right now, temperature 'mild', 11°C. UK. Dew point is also lower in winter [9° today], so condensation is more prevalent.

Comment: There are stand alone humidifiers.  Depending on the house lay out can put one in a central location or use more than one.  The one draw back with them is you need to fill them with water every so often.  They are usually cheap, low maintenance, low electric use units.

Comment: Northeastern US humidity does tend to drop in winter. ... Yeah, I could just get a real ultrasonic humidifier; probably makes more sense. ("Half an idea, and half an hour later I look like a halfwit." Oh well.)

Comment: If the exhaust duct isn't insulated, pushing humid air through it can cause condensation in the cold sections and dripping water.   Nobody wants that.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm assuming you have 89% humidity _outside_ now. The _inside_ humidity is relevant here, though. Since colder air can contain less vapor, the relative humidity quickly raises. But if you heat up that air (as we do to heat our houses), the relative humidity of the warmer air in the house is lower.

Comment: @PMF - Yes. Lower than I expected 62% right now, but this is basically the driest room in the house, the living room. [It takes a while for my interior meter to get stats as it doesn't run all the time. It would take me an hour or so to get full house stats, as I'd have to gather it a room at a time by 'sneakernet'.] Low humidity tends not to be a great concern in the UK… it rains a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bathroom fans are there to remove humidity as having too much is detrimental in a number of ways.  Using a fan to push this humidity throughout the home is both ineffective and ill-advised.  The effects may not be quickly apparent, but be assured, over time they will happen and be unwelcome.

A better approach would be to purchase a humidifier. If you only need a slight increase in humidity a few of the vaporizers that add scents to a room could be the answer.

Comment: Probably true. Well, it was an idea. Not a good one, but an idea.